# Jquery - Permitir que a função seja executada apenas quando ele não estiver rodando

Tags: jquery, funções

Estou com uma certa dificuldade de encontrar uma maneira de bloquear múltiplos *toggles* no meu código. Ou seja quando o cliente clica varias vezes no campo de toggle, o campo fica aparecendo e sumindo várias e várias vezes. Gostaria de saber de que maneira eu posso fazer com que ele consiga *abrir* ou *fechar* o campo apenas quando a ação não estiver sendo executada.

Código que faz o Toogle:

```
<script>
(document).ready(function(){
   $(".botao").click(function(){
   $(this).children( ".classe" ).slideToggle();
   });
});
</script>
```

Desde já Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O slideToggle tem um parâmetro de configuração que faz isso.

Se usares `.slideToggle({queue: false});` ele já não vai acumular instruções.
Curiosamente se carregares muitas vezes rápido ele [parece ter um bug e deixa de funcionar](http://jsfiddle.net/2t25qLhw/)... :/

Assim, como segunda opção usa a *callback* `complete`. Assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".botao").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var animando = $this.data('animando');
        if (!animando) $this.children(".classe").slideToggle(function(){
            $this.data('animando', false);
        });
        $this.data('animando', true);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2t25qLhw/1/